# xrandr: specified screen 3840x2160 not large enough for output HDMI-1 (3840x2160+3200+0)

Tags: 14.04

I've been trying to figure out what the following message means:

```
karl@karl-Dell-Precision-M3800:~/dev/lol/langurama$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1x1 --pos 0x0 --mode 3200x1800
karl@karl-Dell-Precision-M3800:~/dev/lol/langurama$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 2x2 --fb 3840x2160 --pos 1920x0
xrandr: specified screen 3840x2160 not large enough for output HDMI-1 (3840x2160+3200+0)
```

Trying to get an external moniter to sit to the right of my laptop monitor.